# Reload config in Helix editor

Tags: helix-editor

Is it possible to reload `config.toml` without closing Helix?

e.g. `(n)Vim` has `source <config_path>`, is there something similar for Helix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - there's a command aptly named `config-reload`